# iPhone calls and sms: user notifications with hidden status bar

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

my iPhone app uses OpenGL ES in full screen mode (the status bar is hidden), just as the OpenGL ES application template. Using the simulator "Toggle In-Call Status Bar" has no effect, i.e. there is no visual/acoustic notification for the user. I'd like to know whether this is an issue of the simulator or it happens also on the device (I don't have an iPhone). 
If such behaviour is normal, how can I be notified about the incoming call or sms in order to show the status bar that I'm normally hiding?

Also, I would like to know how are in-calls and sms notifications in the device. Will it play some sounds/vibrate? I'm developing an audio application and I don't want calls or sms (and preferably any kind of notification) to disturb acoustically the user, but only a visual feedback.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calls and SMS cannot be avoided (otherwise what is the point of the notification system?). You cannot mute the ringtone or stop vibration. If the status bar has been set to hidden, no form of it will display.

Hope this answers your question,
jrtc27

Comment: If I well understood I can hide the visual notification but can't mute the ringtone. I wished I could do the opposite. However, how can I be notified about the incoming call or sms in order to show the status bar that I'm normally hiding?

Comment: You can't do either. The phone system is not under your control. On iOS 4.0 and later, there is a public CoreTelephony framework that notifies you of incoming calls, but it cannot be used to hide the phone call UI.

Comment: Ok, I've tested my app on an iPhone. Just to clarify, on incoming calls the view disappears. When the call terminates, the app is resumed.